# Detecting protected processes and critical processes from windows driver

Tags: windows, windbg, process

I've got a driver that tamper user-space processes by sending APC calls upon process start using the call `PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine`.

I wish to avoid tampering with any process that is critical for the OS stability, since my APC also eventually decides to kill the process.

So far I've used `PsIsProtectedProcess` and `PsIsProtectedProcessLight` in order to detect protected processes.

However, it appears that there are some processes such as `smss.exe` and `crss.exe` and `wininit.exe` that are defined as critical processes and I also wish to avoid them.

Perhaps anybody knows that difference between protected and critical process, and how can I detect critical process programmatically  from kernel-mode (maybe it has ad-hoc field in EPROCESS ? )

thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems the correct term is *Critical System Service*. There are [API from userland](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/rstmgr/critical-system-services) but I can't find anything for the kernel. So I took a quick look into the RstrtMgr.dll and it seems the list is actually hardcoded...

For the processes:

- system32\csrss.exe
- system32\smss.exe
- system32\lsass.exe
- system32\wininit.exe
- system32\logonui.exe
- system32\services.exe
- system32\winlogon.exe

For the services (specific case for svchost.exe):

- BrokerInfrastructure
- DcomLaunch
- LSM
- Power
- RpcEptMapper
- RpcSs
- SamSs

There is probably another way to achieve that. After all, Windows BSOD if one of these processes is killed.

Edit: It seems `nt!EPROCESS::BreakOnTermination` is what you're looking for.
The *real* field is `nt!EPROCESS::Flags` and the mask 0x2000.
If this bit is set, `PspExitThread` will BSOD with `CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED`.